# Catching a UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, jar, lwjgl, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I know it's not a good practice to catch errors, but in this case, it's important to do it. I'm trying to run a jar which contains a part of my game, but it's giving me an unsatisfiedlink error, but here's it's the funny part:
I'm using this code:

```
System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", new File("lib/natives").getAbsolutePath());
```

But in netbeans, it's giving me this error, BUT, the jar runs. Now, if i change to code, to this:

```
System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", new File("Dist/lib/natives").getAbsolutePath());
```

Now, it runs in netbeans, but the jar it's not working... and i don't get it!, so, i'm trying to use a try/catch to use either of both, and well this is the complete code:

```
try{
    System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", new File("lib/natives").getAbsolutePath());
}
catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e){
    System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", new File("dist/lib/natives").getAbsolutePath());
}
```

and when I run it in netbeans, it's giving me the error of the first line, not an error of the catch part. What's going on? Thanks in advance friends!

Comment: I would not put the second System.setProperty() in the catch block.  Put each of the System.setProperty() calls into a try {} block and in each one set a boolean so as to indicate if the catch was hit or not.  So first try {} block for the first System.setProperty() and if the catch block is triggered because of an error, set a boolean to indicate that the alternative System.setProperty() should be tried in its try block.

Comment: ohh thanks man, but apparently, i'm doing a mess with the code now, because the jar runs by double clicking it, but if i try to run it from the cmd, it's not running.

Answer (score 1):

In code like this:

```
 new File("Dist/lib/natives").getAbsolutePath()
```

you are giving a path "Dist/lib/natives" relative to JRE "user" (or working) directory.  Relative to the value of the system property "user.dir".  The value of this property is set on startup of the JVM, and can vary depending on how the JVM is started.  You should print or log the value of 'user.dir' and observe the difference in each startup-case mentinoed in your question to understand what is going on.

```
System.ou.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```